# Joomla K2 - Create Admin link to Specific Category

Tags: joomla

I want to create an ADMIN link to a specific K2 category, so that I can create quick links for my users to click for each category.

The problem is that when categories are filtered, it seems as though it is done with javascript, and the URL in the address bar changes to /index.php

The ideal solution would be to link to a K2 category like so:

```
/index.php?option=com_k2&category_id=12
```

Any hacks are welcome.

Comment: http://joomtraining.com.au/tutorials/extension/k2/menu-linking-a-category-to-the-menu

Comment: I need a link in the administrator back-end, not the front end.

Comment: I'm not sure how it matters where you put the link. Build a menu and show it in an admin module.

Comment: The issue is that K2 categories effectively have no URL

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in the steps on that page?

Comment: Have you worked with K2 before? Have you ever created a link to a list of items within a K2 category? The steps on that page are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the URL for specifying K2 Categories is as below:

```
option=com_k2&view=items&filter_category=8
```

I thought I had tried that previously.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the code under to the admin menu.
You can take a look at this : http://magazine.joomla.org/component/k2/item/721-Customizing-the-Admin-Menu